# jQuery External Links New Window, honor Relative and Same Domain Links as Internal

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, conditional-statements

I'd like all of my links that are not xxx.domain.com and not "/relative" links to open in an external window. This code shows the problem, which is wrong as the first conditional selector is immediately overwritten by the second. So what I am looking for is multiple conditional selectors and how to combine these two tests, my attempts at which I am having no luck:

try 1)

```
$("#links a:not([href^='/']), #links a:not([href*='.domain.com/'])").live('click',function(e){
$(this).attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

try 2)

```
$("#links a:not([href^='/']).#links a:not([href*='.domain.com/'])
```

try 3)

```
$("#links a:not([href^='/']):not([href*='.domain.com/'])"
```

try 4) (i really had hope for this one)

```
$("#link a:not([href^='/'])").live('click',function(e){
  $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
  $("#links a:is([href*='.domain.com/'])").removeAttr("target");
});


<div id="link"><a href="/relative-path.html">relative</a></div>
<div id="link"><a href="http://www.google.com/">offsite</a></div>
<div id="link"><a href="http://many.domain.com/">onsite</a></div>
<div id="link"><a href="http://any.domain.com/">onsite 2</a></div>
<div id="link"><a href="http://domain.com/">onsite 3</a></div>
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document.links).each( function(){
    this.target = ~this.href.indexOf( "domain.com/") ? "" : "_blank";
});
```

The href property has automatically the expanded url.

Comment: yes it does. very interesting. i tried this with no luck, no alerts:    $(document.links).each( function(){
    alert("link-check");
    this.target = ~this.href.indexOf( "jshell.net/") ? "" : "_blank";
   });

Comment: perhaps some other js is interfering with document.links. can you suggest a method that does not rely on dom collections but rather selectors?

Comment: because i only want some small section of links on my page to be affected (not the whole page)

Comment: i pulled out all other javascript and still same (no effect) anyway, is there a way to use selectors instead of dom collections?

Comment: @HansOg it doesn't really matter what you use, the .each method will still works the same way. Just make sure you pass anchor elements. `document.links` will work just fine if you make the call after DOM is ready. If the alert is not alerting, then whatever you passed to jQuery was empty (the `.each` won't make any calls if the collection is empty). Most likely because document wasn't ready.

Comment: Also you cannot have elements that share an `id`, it must be unique. That can have some side effects.

Comment: of course, i had forgotten document.ready... thanks! now how to make it only test for links within <div id=some-special-links></div>

Comment: i was hoping to use sizzle selectors instead of document.links).filter(div#test a) as well for speed consideration.

Comment: @HansOg `$("#some-special-links a").each( ... ) ` and `document.links` is fastest - it's already there without doing anything

Comment: @HansOg Why did you remove the accept? It is working code and answers the question. The implementation of the code is up to you --- you can make a different question of that if you have problems. This is not how SO works.

Comment: this ended up being the solution i was looking for to maintain the live functionality: `$("div#sign-in a:not([href*='domain.com/'])").live('click',function(e){ $(this).attr("target", "_blank"); });
 $("div#sign-in a[href^='/']").live('click',function(e){ $(this).removeAttr("target"); });`